# How to fix TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I'm passing dataframe from ***mapInPandas*** function in *pyspark*. so I need all values of ID column should be seperated by comma(,) like this `'H57R6HU87','A1924334','496A4806'`

x1['ID'] looks like this

```
H57R6HU87
A1924334
496A4806'
```

Here is my code to get unique ID's, I am getting ***TypeError: string indices must be integers***

```
# batch_iter= cust.toPandas()
  
for x1 in batch_iter:
   IDs= ','.join(f"'{i}'" for i in x1['ID'].unique())
```

Comment: For me working well

Comment: here type of x1 is showing as string. don' t know exactly the issue  ***string indices must be integers*** giving me this

Comment: could you show a more complete example? what is batch_iter?

Comment: @mck it's spark dataframe passed it to function through 'mapInPandas' function. i'm using for loop to iterate through batch_iter dataframe

Comment: @mck ***TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str*** giving me this

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need a loop, try:

```
batch_iter = cust.toPandas()
IDs = ','.join(f"'{i}'" for i in batch_iter['ID'].unique())
```

Or you can try using Spark functions only:

```
df2 = df.select(F.concat_ws(',', F.collect_set('ID')).alias('ID'))
```

If you want to use `mapInPandas`:

```
def pandas_func(iter):
    for x1 in iter:
        IDs = ','.join(f"'{i}'" for i in x1['ID'].unique())
        yield pd.DataFrame({'ID': IDs}, index=[0])

df.mapInPandas(pandas_func)
# But I suspect you want to do this instead:
# df.repartition(1).mapInPandas(pandas_func)
```

Comment: ```df.mapInPandas(cust_checking,schema = 'ID string')``` this is how i'm passing df data frame to cust_checking function. mapInPandas expects for loop so i need to use. here df is spark dataframe converting to pandas dataframe through mapInPandas

Comment: hmm, in that case, why don't you just use spark functions? see my edited answer

Comment: I think mapInPandas is probably unsuitable for this use case, because you need to get the string from the whole dataframe. You can't process the dataframe separately in batches.

Comment: @SS I edited my answer, see if that does what you want?

Comment: yes, same but for me  it's throwing ***TypeError: string indices must be integers***

Comment: @SS could you try using this dataframe: `df = spark.createDataFrame([['a'],['b'],['c']], ['ID'])`

Comment: no, **TypeError: string indices must be integers ** same error i'm getting